# How to configure IIS to map an ISAPI DLL off of a domain root

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi

I have an ISAPI DLL installed under a directory like:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\emsserver\emsserver.dll
```

This is a Delphi RAD Server app.

In IIS Manager (Windows 10), under Root (computer name)  -> Sites -> Default Web Site -> Emsserver, I have a handler set up to handle "*.dll" requests with that DLL. The end result is I can access the app like:

```
http://localhost/emsserver/emsserver.dll/some-action
```

That works fine. All good there, output as expected. But the URL isn't very end user friendly.

**Question:**

Using IIS Manager on Windows 10, how can I configure it so that I can access the application without the DLL portions of the URL?  So, like "`http://localhost/some-action`"?

Seems like it should be a simple enough thing to do, but I'm not seeing how. I tried setting up a handler both in the root server entry in IIS manager, as well as for the 'Default web site', but neither did the trick. I haven't used IIS in 20 years (been almost exclusively Linux & Apache), so I'm a bit out of my usual neighborhood.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Create a rewrite rule.

Comment: @LexLi Awesome, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use url rewrite to achieve this. Download the module from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

[image]

Here is the result of the rule.
[image]

Comment: This does the trick.  For regex I used (.*), and a rewrite of /emsserver/emsserver.dll/{R:1}. This sends all requests to the DLL. So /some-action ends up as /emsserver/emsserver.dll/some-action, which is what I needed.

Comment: Yes, you can modify this way, what I have shown is based on the URL you cited as an example.Using regular judgment is the most accurate method.